# Was it necessary to speak out loud for Force Persuasion?

Tags: star-wars

We see Force Persuasion used in the *Original Trilogy* and every time, the persuader has to speak the words out loud to persuade the victim(for lack of a better word) . I was wondering if it was possible to use Force Persuasion without the persuader having to speak out the words, just using the Force.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. You can use it wordlessly, at least according to the new (Disney Canon) novelisation of RotJ; [Return of the Jedi - Beware the Power of the Dark Side](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!)

> The leather-faced guard and another even tougher-looking one who might
>   be his brother — or sister? — have selected Luke as the first course
>   and push him toward a plank that has extended from the side of the
>   skiff.
>
> **One of the guards — guided by a Jedi mind trick — decides to remove
>   Luke’s handcuffs.**

Comment: Thanks for answering..  But why did Obi-Wan not use it without speaking on Mos Eisley? By speaking it out, he risked getting discovered as a Jedi if another Stormtrooper in the vicinity happened to witness the exchange..

Comment: @mayankbudhwani - Surely it would be weirder if the stormtroopers waved him through without him speaking to them?

Comment: "I don't need to speak to use the Jedi mind trick." "You don't need to speak to use the Jedi mind trick." Anyway, it's possible that all that's needed for simple actions is to motion well enough so that it's obvious what you want the weak-willed guy to do. So, Luke could looked at the guard and have raised his hands a bit, so that the guard understood what he wanted. In the Mos Eisley case, Obi-Wan couldn't easily express what the Stormtrooper should do without saying it.

Comment: Obi-Wan's situation has the added burden of explaining to the viewer just what is happening. If we know the Empire is looking for droids and a bunch of stormtroopers just waves a speeder with 2 droids in it with no questions, viewers will have no idea what just happened.

Comment: I wouldn't call that definitive proof that it's possible. Luke could have easily planted a thought in the guard's mind at another time. For example, when the guards went to retrieve him from his cell(or wherever he was kept) and put the cuffs on him, he could have said something like "Wow, those are really nice handcuffs. It would be a real shame if you lost them to the beast in the pit."

Comment: @Telestia - Well, there's no dialogue listed.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have not read the book. But that's the first thought that crossed my mind when I read your answer.

Comment: @Telestia - I understand that, but *adding dialogue* that's not indicated by the book is to fail Occam's razor.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on Richard's answer: Using the Force in Star Wars is just like casting spells in Harry Potter. Strictly speaking, you can use any Force power with just your mind. However, body gestures (and speech) help in painting the mental image of the desired action and effect. As Luke demonstrated, you can manipulate objects telepathically using just the mind, but using hand gestures normally makes it easier. They are like training wheels on a bicycle.

It's all about making a Force power easier to use by reducing the amount of conscious mental effort needed and more effective by making it more accurate in doing exactly what you want it to do. It's easier to fight with a lightsaber if you're holding on to it and let the Force simply guide your motions rather than having to visualise the lightsaber's orientation, bearing, speed and coordinate position while having your hands tied up. It's easier to verbally instruct a Stormtrooper to unbind you, leave his weapon behind and walk away rather than "program" it directly into the trooper's brain using brain-code.

Comment: Do you have any references that back up your answer?